# How can I remove all tokens with non-word characters in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I am trying to come up with a regex for removing all words that contain non-word characters.

So if it contains a colon, comma, number, bracket etc then remove it from the line, not just the character but the word. I have this so far.

```
$wordline = s/\s.*\W.*?\s//g;
```

Does not have to be perfect so removing strings with dash and apostrophe is ok.

Comment: How could a word contain non-word characters?

Comment: In the context of regular expressions "non-word" characters include things like hyphens (eg, fast-talking) and apostrophes (eg, don't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s/\w*([^\w\s]|\d)+\w* ?//g;
```

Comment: Why not \W instead of ^\w? Just curious if there was a specific reason.

Comment: Yes, \W catches spaces, ^\w\s do not.

Comment: @Telemachus: because he also wants to exclude space characters. \W would include spaces.

Comment: This works except that it still keeps strings containing numbers

Comment: Yeah, I overlooked numbers. Corrected.

Answer (score 3):

```
$wordline = join(" ", grep(/^\w+$/, split(/\s+/, $wordline)));
```

Comment: This is what I would do. Note, however, the \w includes the underscore, _, too. If you don't want that, just specify your own character class.

Comment: OP also said below he doesn't want digits, so that leaves you with /^[A-Za-z]+$/ (or Unicode-aware equivalent).

Comment: one more caveat: depending how tokens are split, Brian G might want to keep the splitting characters as they are. Your solution changes all token separators to <Space>.

Answer (score 2):

```
s/(?<!\S)(?![A-Za-z]+(?:\s|$))\S+(?!\S)//g
```

In regex-land, a "word character" is a letter, a digit, or an underscore (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`).  It sounds like you're using it to mean just letters, so `\w` and `\W` won't do you any good.  My regex matches:

- a bunch of non-whitespace characters: `\S+`
- not preceded: `(?<!\S)` or followed: `(?!\S)` by non-whitespace characters
- unless all the characters are letters: `(?![A-Za-z]+(?:\s|$))`

This will leave behind all the spaces surrounding the words that it deletes.  Dealing with those correctly is a little trickier than you might expect; it's much easier to do in a separate step, e.g.:

```
s/^ +| +(?= |$)//g
```

Comment: [A-Za-z] doesn't deal with Unicode, you probably want to use [[:alpha:]] instead.

Comment: I claim teacher's license. :) With [A-Za-z] it's perfectly clear what you're matching (and what you aren't).  BTW, [[:alpha:]] doesn't deal with Unicode either; it's POSIX-speak for "things classified as letters in the locale of the underlying platform."